# If Cell text is "Text" get adjacent cell text

Tags: google-sheets

I have a need to compare a range of data against a string of data. If there is a match, I would like to get the text or contents of a cell next to it. Any ideas?

Example: Identify name of person with SS# 123-45-6789

[image: Data Range]

Cell contents should return "John"

Comment: Usually, the column with a unique identifier of a person (SS# in your case) appears first. If you had this, the problem would simplify to the straightforward `vlookup` command.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by using the following formulas:

### Formula

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET(A1, MATCH(C1, B1:B3, 0) - 1, 0), "nothing found")

=IFERROR(FILTER(A2:A4, B2:B4 = C2), "nothing found")

=IFERROR(QUERY(A2:B4, "SELECT A WHERE B = '" & C2 & "'"), "nothing found")

=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(C2, {B2:B4, A2:A4}, 2, 0)), "nothing found")
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Google Sheets: If Cell text is “Text” get adjacent cell text](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ggI_GuhqTK13nBL8uDoj8gFHKDiQk5IRN77DhXat-uo/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to @[Jacob](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/85835/60716)'s first offer but shorter mainly for relying on a system error message (`#N/A`) where a value is not found:

```
=index(A:A,match(C2,B:B,0))
```

Can be copied up or down without need to adjust the arrays (but `C2` would adjust).

[INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
[MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)